# Will a coin topple if the center of the coin is just on the corner of the square table?

Tags: torque, rigid-body-dynamics

3/4th of the coin is outside the table and 1/4th is on the inside. Also assume that the center of the coin is just on the inside.

Comment: I tried this on the corner of a table.  It seems that the coin will not fall as long as the center is inside the corner.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the center is inside the corner, the coin will not fall.  The reason is that although it seems 3/4 of the coin's weight is off the table, the coin's center of mass is supported by the corner of the table, and the coin effectively rests on its center of mass.

In this case, gravitational acceleration g does not vary over the extent of the coin. So the coin's center of mass coincides with its center of gravity, and the normal force between table and coin passes through the coin's center.  If such were not the case, for example if the center were outside the corner and off the table, the normal force and the weight of the coin would create torque and the coin would topple.

If the coin's center of gravity were exactly on the corner (instead of inside the corner), any slight air current or vibration might perturb the coin's equilibrium and topple the coin.

Comment: What about the normal reaction from the table. Since only 1/4th of the coin is in contact with the table surface, so the normal reaction will not pass through coin center and hence it will have a torque.

Comment: Gravitational acceleration g is uniform and does not vary over the coin.  Therefore the center of gravity coincides with the center of mass, and the normal force will pass through the coin's center.  I don't see where a torque could arise.  But if the center of gravity were exactly on the corner (instead of inside the corner), any slight air current or vibration might topple the coin.  If the center were outside the corner, then, yes, the normal force and the weight of the coin would create torque.  I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @mikeSmith but the problem states that the CM is on the table, hence more than 1/4 is on the table, and more important, more than half is behind an extended line along either edge of the table. If the CM were exactly on the corner, then the slightest nudge would cause it to fall.